# Try/Except Issue

Tags: python, try-except

I have a program that looks through a list of words and tells the user the possible words that can be made out of the provided letters. I am trying to use try/except for when a ValueError appears when the user puts in a string instead of a number after the comp asks them how many words they would like to see.

For some reason the except doesn't work and it continues to give me a value error. Can someone tell me why this is the case? I just learned about try/except and I don't think I'm doing anything wrong based on what I see.

Here's the whole program (just in case you wanted to see the whole thing instead of the try/except portion.

```
def find_words(s, dict_name):
    found_words = []
    mega_list = [] #list with all the words inside

    # make the text dictionary into a list
    #list without new line
    file_obj = open(dict_name, 'r')
    for line in file_obj:
        edit_line = line.strip('\n')
        mega_list.append(edit_line)
         
    
    # find the result
    for word in mega_list:
        temp_list = list(s)
        if len(word)>len(temp_list):
            flag = False #Ignores words that are longer than the temp_list
            continue
        else:
            flag = True
        for letter in word:
            #print(letter) #prints out every letter in these words
            if letter not in temp_list:
                flag=False
                break
            else:
                #print("Before the remove: " + str(temp_list))
                temp_list.remove(letter)
                #print("The list" + str(temp_list)) 

        if flag and (len(temp_list)>=0):
            found_words.append(word)
   
    return found_words

#For every word in word
    #Found_word = True/False (had it as true)
    #for every character in word


def main():
    nums = '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8','9', '0'
    letters = input("Please put in a set of letters between 1 and 7 characters long.")
    #print(len(letters))
    while (len(letters) < 1 or len(letters) > 7) or letters.isalpha() == False:
       letters = input("Please put in a set of letters between 1 and 7 characters long.")
    
    count = 0
    num_of_words = int(input("How many words would you like to see displayed?"))
    
    #Won't do the except
    try:
        result = find_words(letters, 'enable1.txt')
        while count < num_of_words:
            print(result[count])
            count+=1
    except ValueError:
        print(find_words(letters, 'enable1.txt'))






main()
```

Comment: What's the exact trace of the error?

Comment: If you're trying to catch `int(input("How many words would you like to see displayed?"))` though, it needs to be inside of the `try`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is when you run the following line:

```
num_of_words = int(input("How many words would you like to see displayed?"))
```

You are asking for an input which is immediately converted into an int, and if that input is not an int then you will trigger the ValueError exception.

This line needs to be within your try/except block.